# Como configurar rutas para sub- controladores - CodeIgniter 4

Tags: php, mvc, codeigniter, controller, cms

Estoy haciendo una website que consta de 4 paginas principales (Home, About us, Contact, Gallery) y un sistema de administración de contenido (CMS) en el en el cual podre cambiar a mi gusto el contenido de mi sitio web, Esto lo quiero hacer sin emplear wordpress ni ningun otro cms común. He decidido usar el Framework CodeIgniter en su version 4 para agilizar un poco el proceso de desarrollo. El problema es que no se como configurar las rutas y controladores para la parte del CMS.

Un ejemplo de como quiero que se vean mis rutas es el siguiente:

1) www.midominio.com/home ----> Se mostraria la pagina principal de la website

2) www.midominio.com/dashboard-cms/home ----> Se mostraria la pagina principal del CMS

3) www.midominio.com/dashboard-cms/gallery/add ----> Se mostraria el formulario para agregar imgenes para la pagina de Gallery

En el caso de la primera ruta no tengo problemas en crearlas y crear los controladores y modelos necesarios. 
Mi problema es para hacer funcionar las rutas y controladores para la parte del CMS (segunda y tercera ruta del ejemplo anterior). He creado todos los controladores (tanto del CMS como los de las paginas principales) en la carpeta de Controllers, sin embargo solo consigo hacer funcional las rutas de las paginas principales.

Algun post de referencia, tutorial, guia o codigo que me puedan facilitar para encontrarle solución a este problema?

Comment: Trata de pegar también todo lo que has hecho en tu routes.php Además de eso, ¿todo lo que contiene la págnia de CMS y el formulario de gallery ya existen dentro de tu proyecto de codeigniter?

Comment: @FernandoTorres las paginas del CMS (incluido el formulario de Gallery) estan dentro del proyecto de codeigniter. Los controladores para esas paginas los he creado dentro de la carpeta Controllers, al igual que los controladores de las paginas principales de la website... pero el problema es que no se exactamente qué codigo modificar en el archivo de las routas para que las del CMS me queden como lo expuse en el ejemplo que esta en la pregunta.